# Process large text file concurrently

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8

So I have a large text file, in this case it's roughly 4.5 GB, and I need to process the entire file as fast as is possible. Right now I have multi-threaded this using 3 threads (not including the main thread). An input thread for reading the input file, a processing thread to process the data, and an output thread to output the processed data to a file.

Currently, the bottleneck is the processing section. Therefore, I'd like to add more processing threads into the mix. However, this creates a situation where I've got multiple threads accessing the same BlockingQueue, and their results are therefore not maintaining the order of the input file.

An example of the functionality I'm looking for would be something like this:
Input file: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
Output file: ^ the same. Not 2, 1, 4, 3, 5 or any other combination.

I've written a dummy program that is identical in functionality to the actual program minus the processing part, (I can't give you the actual program due to the processing class containing info that is confidential). I should also mention, all of the classes (Input, Processing, and Output) are all Inner classes contained within a Main class that contains the initialise() method and the class level variables mentioned in the main thread code listed below.

Main thread:

```
static volatile boolean readerFinished = false; // class level variables
static volatile boolean writerFinished = false;

private void initialise() throws IOException {
    BlockingQueue<String> inputQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(1_000_000);
    BlockingQueue<String> outputQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(1_000_000); // capacity 1 million. 

    String inputFileName = "test.txt";
    String outputFileName = "outputTest.txt";

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFileName));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFileName));


    Thread T1 = new Thread(new Input(reader, inputQueue));
    Thread T2 = new Thread(new Processing(inputQueue, outputQueue));
    Thread T3 = new Thread(new Output(writer, outputQueue));

    T1.start();
    T2.start();
    T3.start();

    while (!writerFinished) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    reader.close();
    writer.close();

    System.out.println("Exited.");
}
```

Input thread: (Please forgive the commented debug code, was using it to ensure the reader thread was actually executing properly).

```
class Input implements Runnable {
    BufferedReader reader;
    BlockingQueue<String> inputQueue;

    Input(BufferedReader reader, BlockingQueue<String> inputQueue) {
        this.reader = reader;
        this.inputQueue = inputQueue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String poisonPill = "ChH92PU2KYkZUBR";
        String line;
        //int linesRead = 0;

        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                inputQueue.put(line);
                //linesRead++;

                /*
                if (linesRead == 500_000) {
                    //batchesRead += 1;
                    //System.out.println("Batch read");
                    linesRead = 0;
                }
                */
            }

            inputQueue.put(poisonPill);
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        readerFinished = true;

    }
}
```

Processing thread: (Normally this would actually be doing something to the line, but for purposes of the mockup I've just made it immediately push to the output thread). If necessary we can simulate it doing some work by making the thread sleep for a small amount of time for each line.

```
class Processing implements Runnable {
    BlockingQueue<String> inputQueue;
    BlockingQueue<String> outputQueue;

    Processing(BlockingQueue<String> inputQueue, BlockingQueue<String> outputQueue) {
        this.inputQueue = inputQueue;
        this.outputQueue = outputQueue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                if (inputQueue.isEmpty() && readerFinished) {
                    break;
                }

                String line = inputQueue.take();
                outputQueue.put(line);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output thread:

```
class Output implements Runnable {
    BufferedWriter writer;
    BlockingQueue<String> outputQueue;

    Output(BufferedWriter writer, BlockingQueue<String> outputQueue) {
        this.writer = writer;
        this.outputQueue = outputQueue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String line;
        ArrayList<String> outputList = new ArrayList<>();

        while (true) {
            try {
                line = outputQueue.take();

                if (line.equals("ChH92PU2KYkZUBR")) {
                    for (String outputLine : outputList) {
                        writer.write(outputLine);
                    }
                    System.out.println("Writer finished - executing termination");

                    writerFinished = true;
                    break;
                }

                line += "\n";
                outputList.add(line);

                if (outputList.size() == 500_000) {
                    for (String outputLine : outputList) {
                        writer.write(outputLine);
                    }
                    System.out.println("Writer wrote batch");
                    outputList = new ArrayList<>();
                }
            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So right now the general data flow is very linear, looking something like this:

Input > Processing > Output.

But what I'd like to have is something like this:

[image: Data flow diagram]

But the catch is, when the data gets to output, it either needs to be sorted into the correct order, or it needs to already be in the correct order.

Recommendations or examples on how to go about this would be greatly appreciated.

In the past I have used the Future and Callable interfaces to solve a task involving parallel data flows like this, but unfortunately that code was not reading from a single queue, and so is of minimal help here.

I should also add, for those of you that will notice this, batchSize and poisonPill are normally defined in the main thread and then passed around via variables, they are *not* usually hard coded as they are in the code for Input thread, and the output checks for the writer thread. I was just a wee bit lazy when writing the mockup for experimentation at ~1am.

Edit: I should also mention, this is required to use Java 8 at most. Java 9 features and above cannot be used due to these versions not being installed in the environments in which this program will be run.

Comment: 1. On what data do you base your conclusion that the processing is the limiting factor? 2. If processing is the limtiing factor, is it using almost all of the CPU you have available? 3. Can you just have your reader pass a sequential number to each thread, have that thread output its own file with the number, and put the files together after?

Comment: I base it on the data from the debugger and the CPU usage. One core will almost always be pegged, whereas the other cores will sit at ~40% usage or so. That core that's pegged is doing the processing. Furthermore, debugging the IO threads results in the reader thread being blocked a significant amount of the time due to the fact that it reads faster than the single processor can process. 

The writer thread is limited to the speed of the output of the single processing thread, which isn't that fast. Debugging showed that the outputQueue never exceeded 20 items at its peak.

Comment: Furthermore regarding re-assembling smaller files at the end, that would in theory work, but I really don't want to have 57+ million small files to re-assemble at the very end. The overhead of simply opening a new reader for each file would be absurd.

Comment: If you think the processing stage is the bottleneck, then why not have a single thread loading data batch n+1 while the data batch n is being processed?

Comment: The input thread is already doing that. It loads 2 batches into the inputQueue, and the processing thread takes stuff out of the inputQueue, processes it, and puts it onto the outputQueue.

I think you may have misinterpreted what I said. The file reading is not the bottleneck. The actual processing thread (the one doing operations on each line of the file) is the bottleneck. That bottleneck isn't shown in the code above because as I said, the operations being done on the file lines are confidential and cannot be shown here.

Comment: Your three threads are using one core?

Comment: No. Java uses kernel level threads, so it spreads one thread per core unless there's more threads than cores. In this case, the system I ran this on at work has 4 cores and 4 threads. Since my program only has 3 threads, everything was running simultaneously. 

My home system has 6 cores and 12 threads (Ryzen 5 1600) so I can more easily debug a higher threaded environment. I also have a server debug environment that makes use of a single POWER8 CPU core, with SMT=8, and I'm curious to see the performance difference between a 4 core x86 and the SMT=8 CPU core.

Comment: Essentially what I'm trying to do here lads, is find the happy medium whereby the number of processing threads is enough to completely saturate the IO threads workload. Meaning that the IO threads are never waiting, and are always doing something. Adding more threads than this happy medium would make this an IO bottleneck, adding less makes it a processing bottleneck due to not using all available CPU resources.

Comment: Use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html for outputQueue (add synchronization and wrap items with Comparable).

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov if you could write that up into a formal answer, perhaps with an example, that'd be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was also proposed by Alexei, you can create OrderedTask:

```
class OrderedTask implements Comparable<OrderedTask> {

    private final Integer index;
    private final String line;

    public OrderedTask(Integer index, String line) {
        this.index = index;
        this.line = line;
    }


    @Override
    public int compareTo(OrderedTask o) {
        return index < o.getIndex() ? -1 : index == o.getIndex() ? 0 : 1;
    }

    public Integer getIndex() {
        return index;
    }

    public String getLine() {
        return line;
    }    
}
```

As an output queue you can use your own backed by priority queue:

```
class OrderedTaskQueue {

    private final ReentrantLock lock;
    private final Condition waitForOrderedItem;
    private final int maxQueuesize;
    private final PriorityQueue<OrderedTask> backedQueue;

    private int expectedIndex;

    public OrderedTaskQueue(int maxQueueSize, int startIndex) {
        this.maxQueuesize = maxQueueSize;
        this.expectedIndex = startIndex;
        this.backedQueue = new PriorityQueue<>(2 * this.maxQueuesize);

        this.lock = new ReentrantLock();
        this.waitForOrderedItem = this.lock.newCondition();
    }


    public boolean put(OrderedTask item) {
        ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while (this.backedQueue.size() >= maxQueuesize && item.getIndex() != expectedIndex) {
                this.waitForOrderedItem.await();
            }

            boolean result = this.backedQueue.add(item);
            this.waitForOrderedItem.signalAll();
            return result;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }


    public OrderedTask take() {
        ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while (this.backedQueue.peek() == null || this.backedQueue.peek().getIndex() != expectedIndex) {
                this.waitForOrderedItem.await();
            }
            OrderedTask result = this.backedQueue.poll();
            expectedIndex++;
            this.waitForOrderedItem.signalAll();
            return result;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

**StartIndex** is the index of the first ordered task, and
**maxQueueSize** is used to stop processing of other tasks (not to fill the memory), when we wait for some earlier task to finish. It should be double/tripple of the number of processing thread, to not stop the processing immediatelly and allow the scalability.

Then you should create your task :

```
int indexOrder =0;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                inputQueue.put(new OrderedTask(indexOrder++,line);                    

            }
```

The line by line is only used because of your example. You should change the OrderedTask to support the batch of lines.

Comment: My only concern with this design is that it might not be as performant as Erwin's. When I get time, I will test both designs out and run various performance tests to see which is faster. Whichever design ends up being faster will likely be the chosen answer. I appreciate the effort that went into this though, thank you for showing me how this would be achieved.

Comment: I am looking forward your performance results. If the process batches are same size and the computation is similiar for all of the batches, I would say this solution should be more efficient, because it doesnt add complexity with writing/merging multiple files. Lock contention should not be a problem because your tasks are computation sensitive.

Comment: The mockup may take some time as I am no longer working on this every single day at work, however I have been spending a reasonable amount of time on it at home. We'll see how things go, but I will get back to you all once I finish it.

Comment: During testing of this, I am running into issues with threads not terminating correctly  once the queue is empty, despite my poison pill logic. I'm looking into it.

Comment: Issue resolved. Wasn't related to your queue, the poison pill had a slight bug in it that broke the equality check. Using this method has resulted in processing a 5 GB text file on a 7th gen i7 (with no hyperthreading), in 3 minutes and 30 seconds. Needless to say I was extremely impressed. Thanks a ton for your assistance in this matter.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Comment: Though one thing I am noticing, is that in extremely high threaded environments (>16 processing threads), there appears to be a noticeable amount of waiting going on (for access to the queue). So much so that it appears on the CPU graphs ever so slightly.

Which is making me wonder, would Erwin's answer scale more effectively in extremely high thread environments (ie say, 24 threads, or 32).

Comment: This is hard to say, maybe you should not have so much threads if you don't have enough cores, usually is good to have 2*core threads. Do the threads waiting for the accessing the queue(lock contention) or they are waiting because the queue is full? If the queue is full maybe try to increase maxQueueSize value. Its hard to say if Erwin's answer would be faster, if there would be many threads, than you will be writing from many thread to the same disk which also doesn't have to be best for the performance.

Comment: It's a POWER8 CPU. SMT8 means 8 hardware threads per core. Think of Intel's hyperthreading, and put it on absolute steroids. I've found that 15-16 threads saturates the 2 cores I have available in my linux sandbox. I don't think adding another core would help much though.

I have not checked whether the queue is full, though I somehow doubt it. I believe the cause is lock contention. 

As for many threads writing to the same disk, that's also a valid point, however in a world of SSDs and high speed server back planes, I'm not entirely sure it would be too much of an issue.

Comment: Though one thing I am immensely curious about, is why my 4C/4T x86 physical machine was able to smash the 2C / 16T POWER8 CPU. It's not an IO issue, I benchmarked the IO and eliminated that as a potential cause. The server is virtualised, but I checked the usage of the host box itself, and that is also not the cause. 

Perhaps x86 is just more efficient for a task like this?

Comment: If you think that the problem can be lock contention, than maybe try to increase the processing part, that you will create the batch from more lines with this you should decrease accessing of the queue.

Answer (score 2):

What you could do:

- Take X threads for processing, where X is the number of cores available for processing
- Give each thread its own input queue.
- The reader thread gives records to each thread's input queue round-robin in a predictable fashion.
- Since the output files are too big for memory, you write X output files, one for each thread, and each file name has the index of the thread in it, so that you can reconstitute the original order from the file names.
- After the process is complete, you merge the X output files. One line from the file for thread 1, one from the files for thread 2, etc. in a round-robin fashion again. This reconstitutes the original order.

As an added bonus, since you have an input queue per thread, you don't have lock contention on the queue between readers. (only between the reader and the writer) You could even optimize this by putting things in the input queues in batches larger than 1.

Comment: I will look into doing a mockup of this. If it proves to be performant, I will mark this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why not reverse the flow ?

1. Output call for X batches;
2. Generate X promise/task (promise pattern) who will call randomly one of the processing core (keep a batch number, to pass through to the input core); batch the calls handler into a ordered list;
3. Each processing core call for a batch in the input core;
4. Enjoy ?

Comment: Because to know the amount of batches, I would have to read the entire file into memory. This is not an option due to memory constraints, and is the reason I'm processing the file line by line in the Input thread, rather than just dumping the entire file into ram straight off the bat.

With that being said, it might work if I did it in the context of the limited space the queues provide. The inputQueue usually contains at most 2 batches at any given time. But I could try doing this one batch at a time.

Comment: You don't need to know the amount of batches / the whole file to apply that flow.
You already have the death pill concept; reverse it :)